# Allowing question mark with alphanumeric and spaces with other characters in regex

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I am using PHP `preg_match()` to check a regex list. The function is checking for alphanumeric, spaces, underscores, dashes, asterisk and question mark. But it only takes all the above except question mark and asterisk.

```
return (bool) preg_match('/^[a-z0-9 _-]+$/i', $str);
```

Comment: Tip: You can check your regular expressions [here](http://www.regexr.com/).

Answer (score 2):

> The function is check for alphanumeric, spaces, underscore, dashes, asterix and question mark, but it only takes all the above except question mark and asterix

Because there is no `?` or `*` in your [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Try

```
return (bool) preg_match('/^[\w*? -]+$/', $str);
```

`\w` already contains `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dL6yJ5/1)

Comment: This is the right regex string for this task if the string to check contains always only ASCII letters. But it should be taken into account that `\w` matches any letter according to Unicode specification, not only `A-Za-z`. So it matches also German `ÄÖÜäöüß` and any other word character from any language.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you will need to escape the other ones as they are reserved special characters.

```
return (bool) preg_match('/^[a-z0-9 _-\?\*]+$/i', $str);
```

Comment: The `-` here needs to be escaped or moved to the start/end of the character class. The `?` and `*` are fine without escaping.